# jar file got extra ".jar" extension in lib folder

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, openejb

I am facing a weird issue. I don't know whether it is an "apache-tomcat-5.5.25 with Openejb" issue or Eclipse.

I have one Maven project. I do maven clean and maven install. After that I add that project into "apache-tomcat-5.5.25 with Openejb" server and then publish the project into the server.

The problems start here. When I check the published lib folder, I find that some of the jar  files have an extra extension of ".jar". For example `"xyz.jar"` becomes `"xyz.jar.jar"`.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the problem upstream: What did Maven produce in it's `target` folder?

If it's there, too, run Maven with `-X`, write the log into a file and search that file for the broken JAR name.

Comment: I checked target folder and everything is fine there. problem occurred when i published it to the server.

Comment: What tools do you use to publish? Did you clean the server and publish again to see if it was a one time glitch?

Comment: You didn't say whether you deleted all the files on the server manually before you redeploy.

Comment: "Eclipse" is a platform. Which plug-ins do you use? WTP? Sysdeo Tomcat Plugin?

Comment: i have deleted all the files manually from server.even i have deleted server too and created new server. for publishing i am using Tomcat plugin.

Comment: You seem to be doing everything right. Try the Maven WAR plugin and deploy using Tomcat's admin UI. If that works, it must be a bug in the Tomcat plugin.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11505/discussion-between-mahendra-athneria-and-aaron-digulla)